# Merge dataframes without header

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have foll. dataframes (df_A and df_B):

```
df_A
Col_A     Col_B
23         34
12         18

df_B
23          12
45          10
```

I want to merge them based on Col_A in df_A and 1st column in df_B. Note that df_B does not have any header row. How do I do this? A simple merge would have been:

```
df_A.merge(df_B, on='Col_A')
```

However that does not work in this case becuase df_B does not have Col_A as column.

--EDIT based on @EdChum's suggestion:

TO CLARIFY: I want to merge two dataframes. One has a header, and the other one does not. How do i specify the join column on a dataframe that does not have a header? Can I specify it by location/index?

```
df_B.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 2 columns):
23    1 non-null int64
12    1 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(2)
memory usage: 24.0 bytes

df_B.columns.tolist()
['23', '12']


df_A.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Col_A    2 non-null int64
Col_B    2 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(2)
memory usage: 48.0 bytes

df_A.columns.tolist()
['Col_A', 'Col_B']
```

Comment: Post the output from `df_A.info()` and `df_B.info()` and also the output from `df_A.columns.tolist()` and the same for `df_B` they will have columns despite what you think

Comment: Well it looks like you want to merge like so: `df_A.merge(df_B, left_on='Col_A', right_on='23')`

Comment: thanks @EdChum, updated question to answer your previous query. However, '23' in df_B is not a header, it is a value

Comment: Not according to `df_B.info()`, what does `df_B.columns.tolist()` show

Comment: `df_B.columns.tolist()` shows ['23', '12']

Comment: Well you've answered my question then, you've either imported the file incorrectly or you'll have to merge using my code

Comment: More precisely, while `df_B.info()` is treating 23 as a header, it is not a header for my use-case

Comment: you must have imported with "header=True" while you did not have any.

Comment: @EdChum, I should clarify my query. I want to merge two dataframes. One has a header, and the other one does not. How do i specify the join column on a dataframe that does not have a header? Can I specify it by location/index?

Comment: Nope, you have to fix `df_B` to get what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set column names by `df_B.columns = ['Col_B', 'Col_A']`. Then you can merge dataframes.

```
print df_A
   Col_A  Col_B
0     23     34
1     12     18

print df_B
    0   1
0  23  12
1  45  10

df_B.columns = ['Col_A', 'Col_B']
print df_B
   Col_A  Col_B
0     23     12
1     45     10

out = df_A.merge(df_B, on='Col_A')
print out
   Col_A  Col_B_x  Col_B_y
0     23       34       12
```